# Get multiple url parameters in to isset

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering, how i could get two parameters from URL.
I have a URl like this:
[www.example.com/simplepay-cancel/?r=eyJyIjo1MDE3LCJ0Ijo1MDIyOTI5NTIsImUiOiJDQU5DRUwiLCJtIjoiT01TNTMxNDU1MDEiLCJvIjoiMTE2Njk4ODAyOTk1NjMwIn0%3D&s=h%2FkKbYJWL3EYZiW%2FfGxaUhEkx3d7E0EGBCieMGUjWlT%2B9tUhKBDJU4JglMVpYloj](http://www.example.com/simplepay-cancel/?r=eyJyIjo1MDE3LCJ0Ijo1MDIyOTI5NTIsImUiOiJDQU5DRUwiLCJtIjoiT01TNTMxNDU1MDEiLCJvIjoiMTE2Njk4ODAyOTk1NjMwIn0%3D&s=h%2FkKbYJWL3EYZiW%2FfGxaUhEkx3d7E0EGBCieMGUjWlT%2B9tUhKBDJU4JglMVpYloj)

It containes two parameter the `r` and `s`. Both are encrypted.

I ried to get with the following :

```
if (  (isset($_GET['r']) && isset($_GET['s']))) {
echo 'Hello';  }
```

It work only if i set `r` parampeter in to the URL.
This is a Wp site, and id I set to `s` paramater it fail and goes to 404 page.

How I could get both parameter?

Thank you!

Comment: `s` is generally used for search queries for WordPress, so If I am not wrong then the page becomes a search page, if you can change `s` to something else then I hope you'll not face this issue.

Comment: Thank you! You were right ! Unfortunately, the payment verification server returns with `s` paramater which is as you write, the same as WordPress is using. Now I found a snippet, which is to change the `s` parameter but know all the search function is broken inside the Admin Dashboard.
I used this one: 
[link](https://gist.github.com/jchristopher/035bb07329c1518981db0c532dbe0576#file-functions-php)
Any Idea maybe? I'm pretty beginner in WP and PHP.. :(

Comment: If things are only breaking at the backend, add the `is_admin()` check in your code and only change things for the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Below example will help you to "Get Multiple Parameters with same name from a URL in PHP".